# Technic 4x4 crawler questions

Tags: technic

I have the Technic 4x4 Crawler 9398 fully assembled and in working order, but the rear U-Joint sheared itself in half during normal use. I have a replacement piece but now I can’t get the wheels to line up, because the axle piece that runs through the motor and connects the front and back of the truck won’t line up with the joint unless the wheels are turned while it’s off.

So my question is do I need to disassemble the whole truck to fix this? Or is there a way to correct it without completely stripping the set?

And secondly does anyone know if the tires on the 4x4 X-treme off-roader 42099 will fit the Crawler?

Comment: I can answer your second part: [This](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=42099-1#T=S&O={%22iconly%22:0}) is the 4x4 off-roader. The 9398 monster truck has [these wheels](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15038c01&idColor=11#T=C&C=11) and [theese too](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44772c02&idColor=11#T=C&C=11) but it doesn't say they come in the 42099 monster truck. The 42099's wheels are about 3.5 minifigs tall.